# A better way to call a possibility of mutliple IDs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I have a stripe payment form and when i use diffferent forms that get hidden, i must use separate ID's for the form to appear.  I have found a way to do this but looking to simplify the code if this is possible.

I have a page that has listings for purchase.  Each listing can have variants.  Because of this, I need to create separate Stripe javascript so the credit card form appears.

**I am wondering if there is a simpler route to go in instead of doing the folllowing:**

```
  <script>

  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_1234567890');


  var elements = stripe.elements();



  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      lineHeight: '24px',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  card.mount('#card-element');

  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {

      var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
      var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
      form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

      // Submit the form
      form.submit();
    }



</script>

<script>

var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_1234567890');

var elements = stripe.elements();

var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '24px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

#HERE IS USE DIFFERENT CARD ID

card.mount('#card-element-2');

card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    form.submit();
  }



</script>
```

**One of the forms:**

```
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="card-element-2">
          Credit or debit card
      </label>
    <div id="card-element-2" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
...
...
```

As you see, if you look closely, there are different `id`'s being called in each separate script.  I have a commented out like `#HERE I USE DIFFERENT CARD ID`

**Question**, is there a way where I can simplify this code and call the possibility of multiple ID's instead of having long javascript like the way i do?

I then, in the view, have separate credit card forms with different ID's.  It is like this because when one form is appearing, another is hidden.

Comment: Consider using some other attribute. IDs are to uniquely identify elements, if you want multiples, identify them by class or data-* attribute.

Comment: This is valid but with more than few element, use a factory function.

Comment: @RobG When i use classes, the form won't appear.  I think its a security feature from Stripe

Comment: This likely belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not sure what exactly your question is here. If you want to do the same or _mostly_ the same stuff multiple times, that is usually where you use a _loop_ …

Comment: @Cryptopat thanks ill look into figuring that out.  From what i read it should work but i made a few attempts to no avail so far but should work out.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst thanks i made a post there :)